# How does the Ramond-Neveu-Schwarz dual model avoid fermion - diquark vertexes?

Tags: string-theory

In the dual resonance model with fermions, as described for instance in Maldestam "[Manifestly Dual Formulation of the Ramond Model](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269373901639?via%3Dihub)", an incoming pair of fermion-antifermion can scatter via a "quark-antiquark meson" or a "zero quark meson" of the Neveu-Schwarz model. In fact if the former happens in the s-channel, then the latter is the one in the t-channel.

Now, if two incoming fermions interact, how is that they do not make what we could call a "quark-quark meson"?

It could appear also in other situations via duality, consider in

```
1   3
 \ /
  o
 / \
2   4
```

the non planar fermion (1) + antifermion (2) scattering, where the antifermion exits in (3); then the channel (1)+(3) --> (2) + (4) also seems to produce a diquark. Or consider an scattering via zero-quark meson, reverse one of the quark lines, say between (3) and (4) and then again check the (1)+(3)--> (2)+(4).

At the end of the mentioned article there is a final note that perhaps is just a reply to a reviewer: "*We could also construct a model with qq intermediate states...*" but I have not read further consideration of it in other articles. There is some reference to alternative assignments of g-parity, so I wonder if GSO projection is involved here.

PS: I read that Shapiro did a paper "*showing that nonorientable graphs do not enter theories with SU(n) flavors incorporated `a la Chan-Paton.*" and it could be argued that all the graphs showing diquarks have at least one twist. Perhaps this is a way towards an answer. Other arguments seem to be just to impose conditions such as "triality zero".

And of course I am assuming that diquarks are possible in the bosonic string theory with Chan-Paton charges, and perhaps it is that I am simply wrong at this level already.

Comment: a related though: how is it that string theorists, even after discovering susy, did not discovered any trace of SU(3) in the strings? The property antisymetric(3x3)=3 looks pretty stringy.